# How do I increment a value using an SQL update statement for each TAG record value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am executing a SSIS ETL process that loads data into a table and uses a execute SQL statement as the last component of execution to update TAG values based on the value of the Content column. An example is

```
update [payments].[MTFileValidationData_UAT]
set TAG = 'Header'
where left(content,3) = '{1:' and [TransactionId] = ?
```

This is actually done for a series of different tags. Once this is done, there is a column called `FileSequenceNumber` that needs to be updated with a number for each tag so I can eventually compare UAT and Production files against each other for testing purposes.

What I need as well is to update the column `FileSequenceNumber` to give me a sequential number per each tag for each filename.

Expected result:

```
RowID | TransactionId | FileName | FileType | Tag | Content | Location | FileSequenceNumber |
------+---------------+----------+----------+-----+---------+----------+--------------------+
1        9052312        ABCFile    NULL       Header   XXX     October           1
2        9052312        ABCFile    NULL       Header   ZZZ     October           2
3        9052312        ABCFile    NULL       Header   YYY     October           3
3        9052312        ABCFile    NULL       32B   YYY        October           1
3        9052312        ABCFile    NULL       32B   YYY        October           2
3        9052312        ABCFile    NULL       32B   YYY        October           3
```

Comment: Do you only need to update the rows that are currently updated?  Or do additional rows need to be updated?

Comment: @GordonLinoff All rows need to be updated. Tag data is populated as a whole from an update statement. The same with FileSequenceNumber. All rows need to be populated by an update statement.

Comment: There are two questions here, yeah? 1) how to populate TAG for assorted content values. 2) how to backfill FileSequenceNumber.  Perhaps your question could be improved by showing the state of the table A) post data flow (initial state).  B) Post tag backfill  C) post file sequence number fill

Comment: No it’s only one question. I am successfully populating tag data. What I need is a sequence number per each tag per each file name.

Comment: @billinkc it’s only one question. Tag data is successfully populated. I just wanted to show an example of how it is populated so I can attempt to populate tag data in the same fashion. I simply need a sequence number for each tag per each file name. That’s it.

Comment: So literally each time the tag changes, you want to start from 1 and assign a unique number to all the values in tag? Would the sequence numbers for Header have been equally correct if they were populated as 3,1,2 in the example?

Comment: @billinkc no they need to populate in the order at which the record gets inserted into the table. So the first tag that gets inserted needs to have a file sequence of 1, same with 2 and 3. In that order. that way they can be compared against another table with the same sequence number. each record will be commopared by transaction ID, file name, and sequence number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking to use the fancy windowing functions available with SQL Server 2012+. Specifically, [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
UPDATE
    T
SET
   FileSequenceNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Tag ORDER BY RowID)
FROM
    dbo.myTable AS T;
```

The `partition by` resets the counter each time the tag changes

The `order by` specifies how the sequence should be generated within the tag column.

As noted from the comment, window functions can only appear in the select or oder by clause so we have to modify to meet the criteria. DBFiddle for working repro  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d731c14c9e15d70eb3b1d34f7b0f61a8

```
UPDATE
    T
SET
    T.FileSequenceNumber = TI.FileSequenceNumber
FROM
    dbo.SO_61461648 AS T
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        FileSequenceNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TI.Tag ORDER BY TI.RowID)
    ,   TI.RowID
    FROM
        dbo.SO_61461648 AS TI
    ) aS TI
    ON TI.RowID = T.RowID;
```

In the event that the supplied data was accurate and there are 4 rows with the same RowID, then you'd need to take a heavy handed approach and dump the table and reload it.

```
-- Heavy handed approach to dump the table and reload with new value in case RowID is not unique

declare @Intermediary table
(
    RowID int NOT NULL
,   Tag varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
    DELETE T
        OUTPUT DELETED.RowID, DELETED.Tag
        INTO @intermediary(RowID, Tag)
    FROM
        dbo.SO_61461648 AS T;

INSERT INTO
    dbo.SO_61461648
SELECT
    D.*
,    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.Tag ORDER BY D.RowID)
FROM @Intermediary AS D;

SELECT * FROM dbo.SO_61461648 AS T order by RowID, FileSequenceNumber;
```

Comment: This may work, my question is, do I just run this at the very end ONCE after all data is set? Thanks.

Comment: When I try to run this I get "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses)

Comment: Fiddle has been doctored

Comment: I got it, Billinkc I just want to thank you once again for the help. It works perfectly.